# How to configure userInfoUri and tokenUri properties dynamically for federation on each request in spring security?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-oauth2, federation

currently we are supporting federation . I have a scenario where based on authorization code I need to modify userInfoUri and tokenUri on each request .

Basically its dependent on authorization code because of which uri may change .

Is there a way in which based on some condition below created userInfoUri and tokenUri can be modified ?

```
  @Bean
    public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(this.ciscoClientRegistration());
    }


public ClientRegistration ciscoClientRegistration() {
        return ClientRegistration
        .withRegistrationId("project")                         .clientId("clientid")
.clientSecret("clientsecret")
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .redirectUri(redirectUri)
                .scope(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(scope.split(","))))
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationUri(authorizationURI)
                .tokenUri(tokenURI)
                .userInfoUri(userInfoURI)
                .userNameAttributeName(userNameAttributes)
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: *I need to modify userInfoUri and tokenUri on each request .* So you want to log in every request again? That's a real strange requirement. Why? You only need to log in with the first request.

Comment: yes we are using latest spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client from spring boot 3.1.5 -
@dur

Comment: we have our token authentication server hosted in multiple regions , So based on authorization code we need to route token generation request to specific token authentication server - @dur